# Basic Babel transformation fails with stack trace

Tags: javascript, babeljs

A very simple Babel configuration is failing, and I'm not sure why. Using syntax plugins in place of the transformers *does* work, so Babel is capable of correctly parsing this example.

I know using the decorators proposal without `{ legacy: true }` results in an error, as it's not yet finalized how private members will interact with decorators. However, there is no such issue with the legacy proposal (or so I thought).

Babel configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
  ],
};
```

File to build:

```js
class Foo {
  @Decorator
  #bar = '';
}
```

Attempting to build results in the following error (modified only to remove irrelevant path information):

```
TypeError: Property value expected type of string but got null
    at Object.validate (./node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:161:13)
    at validate (./node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:17:9)
    at builder (./node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/builder.js:46:27)
    at Object.StringLiteral (./node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/generated/index.js:335:31)
    at ./node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/transformer-legacy.js:93:83
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at applyTargetDecorators (./node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/transformer-legacy.js:84:32)
    at applyMethodDecorators (./node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/transformer-legacy.js:70:10)
    at PluginPass.ClassExpression (./node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/transformer-legacy.js:156:94)
    at newFn (./node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
```

This is performed on a fresh install. Dependencies are:

```
@babel/cli@^7.4.4
@babel/core@^7.4.5
@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@^7.4.4
@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@^7.4.4
```

NB: I don't actually need to transform the decorators — that's being handled by another plugin. I've tried swapping the decorator transformer for the syntax plugin, but I then receive an error stating that decorators are not enabled.

Is this a bug in Babel? If anything, it should fail with a "nice" error message, not a random stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [a discussion on Babel's GitHub](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10144), this is the correct behavior.

Quoting @nicolo-ribaudo's response,

> The old decorators proposal didn't specify any interaction with class private properties.
>
> In loose mode, they could probably be handled similar to how public loose fields are decorated, but it will require a big refactoring of our legacy decorators plugin.
>
> In the meantime, I'd like to see there a human-friendly error message.